# How do I compute the weighted median income?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and not very familiar with it. I want to calculate the At-Risk-Of-Poverty indicator (income is below 60% of the national median equivalized disposable income; `DB020` = country, `HX090` = equivalized disposable income) with the `EU-SILC` data. I use the laeken package and tried this code:

```
hhregdata <- hhregdata %>% 
                   group_by("DB020") %>% 
                   mutate(arp = "HX090" < (weightedMedian("HX090", weight="DB090")*0.6))
```

But i get the error:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>     'x' must be a numeric vector

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need quotes to call variables

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the R tag we ask for reproducible examples (check out the R tag description for more info).